# Is there a mathematical operator describing the sum of (unique) pairwise multiplications of a vector?

Tags: vectors, terminology

Let $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in X$ be a (column) vector and consider the operator $f: X\to\mathbb{R}$ that computes the sum of all unique pairwise multiplications of $x$. For example, for $n=3$, $f$ is defined as

$$f(x) = x_1x_2 + x_2x_3 + x_1x_3$$

I know we can write this as $f(x) = x^\top Ax$ where $A$ is the (strictly) upper triangular matrix of ones, but does this operator have a name (and consequently some studied properties)?

Comment: I think A is not upper triangular. It has a 1 at the lower left corner. This is a matrix that represents a permutation.

Comment: Please elaborate. For $n=3$, $x^\top Ax=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\begin{pmatrix} 
0&1&1 \\
0&0&1\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{pmatrix} = (x_1,x_2,x_3)\begin{pmatrix} 
x_2+x_3\\
x_3\\
0
\end{pmatrix}=x_1(x_2+x_3)+x_2x_3=x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3$

Comment: Oh I meant $\begin{pmatrix} 0 &1 &0\\ 0 &0 &1\\ 1 &0 &0\end{pmatrix}$.